# Specify a width for a grid column

Tags: wpf, grid

I'm using a grid to define a form with this column template :

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

But I need for a specific row to use another column template :

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4">N°</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Name="idNum"></TextBox>
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Name="idVoie" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValue="."></ComboBox>
<TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Name="idAdr"></TextBox>
```

with the first three field being `1*` and the last field using the free space.
Of course, I can't specify the width directly in the field with percent.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested grid for that particular row, which spans all four columns of your outer grid:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">N°</Label>
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="idNum"></TextBox>
  <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Name="idVoie" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValue="."></ComboBox>
  <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Name="idAdr"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Note I'm assuming when you refer to `1*` you mean as relative to the grid you already have, i.e. the same size as the first and third columns. Therefore you have a total of `8*` across the row, and I've calculated the relative widths for your row to be `1*`, `1*`, `1*`, `5*`.